# Is it possible to separate one line string text into multi-line in MacOS

Tags: macos, command

I am new to commands , I have a following one line string snippet[image]

is it possible to make syntax output display like below
[image]

I tried using `cut -d',' -f 6,12,......` , but If I have 100000 fragments or more, how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `awk`. The following will split the input into chunks of 6 comma-separated columns:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<NF; i+=6){for(j=0; j<5; j++) { printf "%s,", $(i+j) } print $(i+5) } }'
```

**Explanation**

- `-F,` uses comma as the input field (i.e. column) separator
- `for(i=1; i<NF; i+=6) {` steps over columns, 6 at a time
- `for(j=0; j<5; j++) {` steps over the first 5 columns in the set of 6
- `printf "%s,", $(i+j)` prints the *i+j*-th column followed by a comma (and no new line)
- `print $(i+5)` prints the last (6th) column followed by a newline

Comment: Thx :) nice explanation ! And also I have been tried using perl  ```cat sample.txt | perl -ple 's/(.*?,){6}\K/\n/g'```